# What are the means I can use to disable Alt + *X* in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Essentially, in our system, our users enter reports and they find all manners of ways to accidentally lose their work on them so we have been locking down everything that they can press that might make them lose data. F5, CRTL + R, CTRL + W and Backspace are all disabled; all bars in IE are hidden and there is a confirmation dialog on the close button.

I have not had any luck in disabling ALT + F4, ALT + ←, ALT + →

I have tried disabling them with javascript. However my method is not working.

```
if (window.event.altKey) {
    if (window.event.keyCode == 115) {
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        window.event.returnValue = false;
        window.event.keyCode = 0;
        window.status = "Alt + F4 is disabled on all popups";
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm thinking I may require more drastic methods.

In this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798363/how-can-i-disable-altf4-event-in-ie-browser%20here), he suggests this may be possible with shdocvw.dll but I'm not sure what that would entail.

Is there a means to disable the Alt + *X* combination or perhaps work around I can exploit for them?

Comment: Can you implement a custom browser? If so, why don't you just use Qt's [QWebView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebview.html) and make a single-page fullscreen browser.

Comment: I've answered this question before... I cannot find the question right now, but basically, don't do what you are doing.  Simply instead use a JavaScript callback for when someone begins navigating away from your page.

Comment: localstorage to restore work could be a different approach.

Comment: Out of interest what do you mean when you say they lose their work? Seems madness all this extra effort...

Comment: Have you tried using local storage/user data?

Comment: No, what is local storage / user data? Will that work on ie 6 - 8?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray They open a report type a bunch of stuff for 20 minutes without pressing save and then accidentally mash a key that closes the window or navigates away from the page they are on.

Comment: I've always said users are stupid! ;)

Comment: Take a look at my answer, I posted a link about how to use userdata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mess with default browser behavior. If you're worried about users accidently closing the window, just use the `onbeforeunload` event:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return 'You will lose all unsaved changes.';
};​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/rPLWd/

Comment: It's not "you shouldn't mess" but rather "you definitely can not mess".

Comment: Dang, I can't use this option as this is a touch screen app and those buttons are too small. :(

Comment: @BiffMaGriff how does a user press alt-f4 on a touch screen?

Comment: @jbabey With the keyboard, the touchscreen replaces the mouse.

Comment: @BiffMaGriff they can use left/right and enter to deal with the popup.

Comment: @jbabey My users will not understand that. :(

Comment: Here we go, I'm going to use this. `onbeforeunload="return 'Press ESC to continue working, Press ENTER to leave and lose unsaved changes';"` They'll still complain about the font size but that will serve my purposes.

Comment: @BiffMaGriff there's not much you can do about the font size - that dialog is controlled by the browser and there's no (reliable) way to mess with it. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498988/confirm-box-styling)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't disable those combinations - and for good security reasons (otherwise any webpage could potentially hijack your computer...).

Your best bets are (in decreasing order of functionality):

- continually saving the work on the server (think Google Docs)
- using client-side storage ([WebStorage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) and the like)
- implement a onBeforeUnload handler that asks for confirmation before navigating away from the page (or closing the browser)
- forcing your users to use browsers that save the state of the page (including forms and whatnot) when exiting (examples include Firefox and, IIRC, Chrome)